# Django: find all OneToOneFields pointing to a Model

Tags: django-orm, inspect, one-to-one

I'm writing routines to inspect an instance and find all its relations (e.g. using `instance._meta.get_all_related_objects()`) but I can't find a way to get relations involving a OneToOneField.

For instance, with these two models:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    ...

class Extension(models.Model):
    ...
    main = models.OneToOneField(Main, primary_key=True)
```

given a 'Main' instance I should find its related OneToOne objects/classes (obviously without kwowing their names).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

def all_models_with_oto(the_model):
    """
    Returns all models that have a one-to-one pointing to `model`.
    """
    model_list = []
    for model in models.get_models():
        for field in model._meta.fields:
            if isinstance(field, models.OneToOneField):
                if field.rel.to == the_model:
                    model_list.append(model)
    return model_list
```

List comprehension version (ironically slower, probably due to `any` and nested lists):

```
def all_models_with_oto(the_model):
    """
    Returns all models that have a one-to-one pointing to `model`.
    """
    return [model for model in models.get_models() if any([isinstance(field, models.OneToOneField) and field.rel.to == the_model for field in model._meta.fields])]
```

Comment: @Don - This will return a list for you and you can use it like: `all_models_with_oto(Main)`.

Comment: @Don - nah, that would just create problems. It runs about 10 times faster than a single `objects.get(pk=X)` query (according to `timeit`). The models are already in a registry in RAM. I made a list comprehension version (which I've added to the answer), but it ended up running slower :(